# Is there any current method of authenticating and storing user fingerprint data with a Xamarin mobile app?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, fingerprint, biometrics

From what I understand, the OS controls all fingerprint data from a device's scanner. I'm building an application where I need to be able to store fingerprint data for a number of users to authenticate them on jobsites, so I won't be able to manage fingerprints through the device only.

Is there any other option for me to implement fingerprint authentication in Xamarin? I've looked into fingerprint.com/fingerprintJS but they don't have support for Xamarin applications at the moment.

Comment: you need to look at what capabilities are provided by the underlying OS.  Xamarin can't do anything that the OS doesn't allow.  iOS does not expose any underlying biometric data.  Android may be more flexible, or you may have to rely on a third party biometric dongle.  Also, I don't think fingerprint.com does what you think it does - it appears to be a device identification service, not a biometric one.